# Automatically make or update a copy real-time on another hard drive volume whenever files are saved to a particular folder

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

EDIT:  The main recommendations for Windows that were offered in answers to the question cited as the reason for closing this one as a duplicate, do not work in real-time.  I've downloaded Yardis and although it's been set up to recognize changes real-time, it does not do so. Same problem with DSynchronize, whose documentation indicates that this feature is "experimental".

### So if we could re-open this question, that would be good.

Whenever I save or update a file to a particular designated folder on my C:\drive I would like to make or update a copy on my network-attached storage device, ideally saving the copy to the NAS as a version rather than overwriting a copy there, if possible.

I have Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. Is there any feature built-in that can accomplish this?  It has to be a real copy, not merely a pointer. I'm trying to achieve some redundancy for especially critical documents (in a variety of formats) that change frequently throughout the day.

P.S. I am looking for folder-level granularity; I wouldn't want this to happen for every file on the C: volume.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete clone of your primary disk (i.e. do you want to be able to boot off your backup), or just a real time backup of all documents?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I was using a different browser when I asked the question and did not see the replies/comments until today. No, not a complete clone, and not all documents -- only the files in a specified folder.

Answer (score 3):

As Synctoy doesn't automatically sync files I went back to digging for something that could. I came up with this program here: [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com).

From what I've read in the product description it looks like it should work well for you:

> On File Change
>   Analyze (and maybe Sync) this job when any file changes in left or right folder or its sub-folder.
>
> Starting with GoodSync ver 9.1.4, we employ our new Real Time Sync mechanism that:
>
> - Monitors file system for changes,
> - Analyzes only files that were reported changed by file system, no full Analyze.
> - Syncs files that have changed.
> - Full Analyze is performed only on the 1st iteration of Real Time Sync.

[Source](http://www.goodsync.com/support/manual)

---

There's a handy tool by Microsoft called [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) that might do what you want.

Otherwise you could look into a solution based around some kind of Source Control like Git.

Comment: Thanks, this looks as though it will do exactly what I wanted, with its Echo mode (copying left to right).

Comment: After using it, it seems one must manually sync the folders, which is not what I looking for. It's still a useful utility but not automatic. I was hoping for a "daemon". I'm going to un-accept the answer in order to keep the question alive.

Comment: @mrblint - GoodSync supports doing scheduled changes.  It will even watch for ANY changes and do an update automatically.

Comment: His comments are specifically targeted towards SyncToy, which was my original suggestion. I had made an edit to my answer after he unmarked it as accepted.